# Multithreading with map and pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I'm trying to follow [a multithread example](https://chriskiehl.com/article/parallelism-in-one-line) and adapt it to my code. This is the simplest explanation about multithreading I've read and it's easy to implement when you have a list:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool 
pool = ThreadPool(4) 
results = pool.map(my_function, my_array)
```

Which is the multithreaded version of:

```
results = []
for item in my_array:
    results.append(my_function(item))
```

The problem, is that for my example I've a dictionary and I'm stuck at the first lines of code as I have to create a function but I don't see how I can do that, because I need to work with both the keys and values of the dict inside the function.

For example, for this single thread version:

```
thisdict =  {
"brand": "Ford",
"model": "Mustang",
"year": 1964
}

for key in thisdict: 
    print(key, thisdict[key])
```

How can I adapt it to use map and pool?

Thank you,

Comment: It's not the best idea to call `print` in multithreading

Comment: It's just for the example. The real code I've to work with have to deal with some get requests and inserting into DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `Pool.map()`, it's an example:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

def my_function(d):
    return d ** 2

my_array = [*range(20)]

pool = ThreadPool(4) 
results = pool.map(my_function, my_array)
print(results)
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, 121, 144, 169, 196, 225, 256, 289, 324, 361]
```

**Upd.**
Version for `dict`:

```
def my_function(item):
    key, value = item
    return {"recieved_key": key, "recieved_value": value}

thisdict =  {
    "brand": "Ford",
    "model": "Mustang",
    "year": 1964
}

pool = ThreadPool(3)
results = pool.map(my_function, thisdict.items())
print(results)
```

Comment: I don't see any dictionary in your example!

Comment: @CreekBarbara, added.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a loook at it this afternoon. I'll get back to you if it works for my project.